# Compiling ejabberd with Elixir 1.4.4 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc, ejabberd

Good morning.  I have created a new phoenix 1.3 app on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29), Erlang 19.3 and Elixir 1.4.4.  I added ejabberd as a dependency ({:ejabberd, ">= v2.1.13", github: "processone/ejabberd"}) and ran mix.deps without error.  I try to compile the project and it fails with the following:

==> fast_xml
Unchecked dependencies for environment prod:
* p1_utils (Hex package)
  the dependency is not locked (run "mix deps.get" to generate "mix.lock" file)
* elixir_make (Hex package)
  the dependency is not available, run "mix deps.get"
could not compile dependency :fast_xml, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile fast_xml", update it with "mix deps.update fast_xml" or clean it with "mix deps.clean fast_xml"
==> sebago
** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies

If I try to compile fast_xml from the deps directory using rebar (rebar 2.6.4 18 20170508_132308 git 2.6.4-6-g2a52f60), I initially get the error that it is missing dependencies so I do mix deps.get followed by mix compile and get the following:

==> fast_xml
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile'.  Stop.
** (Mix) Could not compile with "make" (exit status: 2).
Depending on your OS, make sure to follow these instructions:

- Mac OS X: You need to have gcc and make installed. Try running the
  commands "gcc --version" and / or "make --version". If these programs
  are not installed, you will be prompted to install them.
- Linux: You need to have gcc and make installed. If you are using
  Ubuntu or any other Debian-based system, install the packages
  "build-essential". Also install "erlang-dev" package if not
  included in your Erlang/OTP version. If you're on Fedora, run
  "dnf group install 'Development Tools'".

gcc --version:

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

make --version:

GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0

Does anybody have a suggestion where to start?

Thanks.

Comment: I have gotten around the problem by modifying the mix.exs file for ejabberd.  I changed the fast_xml dependency from:

`{:fast_xml, "~> 1.1"}` to 

`{:fast_xml, ">= 1.1.13", github: "processone/fast_xml", override: true}`

and all compiled fine.